# How to Run Docker Linux Containers on Windows Server 2016 Build 14393

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, linux-containers

I'm in a situation where:

- I have no choice of server OS (Windows Server 2016 Build 14393).
- And no choice of container OS (I need Linux Containers).
- And I don't need Docker EE (Enterprise), CE (Desktop Edition) will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to get Linux containers without hacky workarounds is to download **Docker Community Edition 2.0.0.3** 2019-02-15

Link: https://download.docker.com/win/stable/31259/Docker%20for%20Windows%20Installer.exe

Page with all versions: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/

Simply download/copy the file to the Windows Server 2016 machine and run it.

It can also run offline for air gapped systems.

Uncheck the "Use Windows containers" during setup. Unchecked by default.

You will get a message after installing saying that windows so and so is deprecated. Click OK.
[image]

Log out and log back in.

If you hadn't installed Hyper-V it'll prompt you to do it automatically. Allow it, let it finish and restart. You're good to go now.

I've tested this by running several Linux containers, it works fine. If I'm missing something do share for the benefit of others. The downside is you cannot update to a later version of Docker.

Update:
Disclaimers:

- This can help you avoid the hardware limitations and complexities of using LCOW with Docker-EE for Windows.
- It is more recent than the latest official version of LCOW available.
- This won't let you run Windows and Linux containers in parallel. You can only run one or the other.
- This also won't start docker automatically at startup (not until you login). To start docker without login you'll need to add Docker Desktop Executable to Windows Task Scheduler and configure it to run on startup whether user is logged in or not. You'll have to provide an account for it (ideally a service account, or an account with a permanent password)

Comment: Hello Waleed, what Windows features did you have enabled ? Hyper-V, Nested Virtualization? Was your Windows Server a bare metal machine or a VM?

Comment: Hi @Fjordo this was an air gapped VM with nested virtualization. Hosted using VMware. It's not the best place to host docker containers but it was the only option made available to me. In terms of windows features you'll need Hyper-V and containerization.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to work within a bare metal server and Hyper-V and containerization enabled. Thanks

Comment: lol, after hours of struggling with this... finally a fine working solution. thanks!

Comment: Tried this now a few times, same version of windows (14393), and it's consistently failing to boot Docker. `Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running`. Anyone came across this issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to enable "Hyper-V" and "containerization" features on Windows Server.